# Search a specific word in EXCEL using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Im a beginner with Excel VBA 
my question is if I have string in a cell like `"MyNameIsHammadAndImFromIreland"`.
All cells have strings/sentences but there is no spaces. 
How can I find if the cell includes the word `"Ireland"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VBA, just use a formula:

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Ireland",""))<LEN(A1),"Word Found","Word NOT found")
```

---

If you really want VBA then:

```
hasWord = InStr(Range("A1").Value, "Ireland") > 0 '// returns TRUE or FALSE
```

Comment: If you're going to use a worksheet function, why wouldn't you use `Find()` or `Search()`?

Comment: Swings and roundabouts, different ways of doing the same thing - depends what you prefer.

Comment: Sure, but that's the exact purpose of those functions. You're pounding a nail with the end of a screwdriver.

Comment: It's one of the many ways possible to achieve the same result, however if you feel that the OP would benefit from a shorter syntax then post an answer and explain why - the more input from others, the more the people who come to this site will learn new things.

Comment: is there a way i can edit this code to make it work:
   " If Cells(i, 6).Value = "Ireland" Then "
now it works only if the cell has the word Ireland alone !!

Comment: @Jedani I've given a VBA example in my answer - use the `InStr()` method.

Comment: InStr(Cells(i, 6).Value, "Ireland").................. Worked perfectly .......... Thank you so much @Macro Man

Comment: @Jedani No worries, also take the time to review the other answer that was posted as this may give you a complete solution. Don't forget to mark one as the answer too.

Answer (score 2):

The following VBA code will iterate through the used cells in a given worksheet and find any that match the given criteria.  At the end, a message box is displayed showing a list of cells that contain the search term.

This functionality is equivalent to using the 'Find All' option you can choose when you use the normal find functionality available by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Find()

        Dim rngResult As Range
        Dim strToFind As String

        'Set to your desired string to find
        strToFind = "Ireland"

        'If the string you are searching for is located in
        'the worksheet somewhere, you can set the value
        'like this:  strToFind = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        'This assumes your search term is in cell A1 of the
        'Sheet1 worksheet.

        'Look in the used range of a given worksheet
        'Change Sheet1 to match your worksheet name
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

                'Find the first cell that contains the search term
                Set rngResult = .Find(What:=strToFind, LookAt:=xlPart)

                'If it is found, grab the cell address of where the
                'search term can be found
                If Not rngResult Is Nothing Then
                        Dim firstAddress As String, result As String
                        firstAddress = rngResult.Address

                'Loop through the rest of the cells until returning
                'to the first cell that we had a match in.
                Do
                        'Record the cell address of the match
                        'to the result string
                        result = result & rngResult.Address & ","

                        'Go to next cell containing the search term
                        Set rngResult = .FindNext(rngResult)

                'Exit the loop when we reach the starting point
                Loop While rngResult.Address <> firstAddress

                'Output the list of cells that contain the string to find
                MsgBox "Found """ & strToFind & """ in cell(s): " & result

                End If
        End With

End Sub
```

Be sure to set `strToFind` to your desired string, and change `Sheet1` to match the name of whichever sheet you want to search over.